# Excel VBA Macro Column Compare Not Working

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kMDw.png)I'm trying to compare a list of items in column G to a list of items in column C.
My list in column C belongs to several different clients, and my macro is not working correctly. I need the macro to show the differences in column G and C by highlighting them. My macro is working correctly for the first client, but isn't working correctly for the remaining clients. The highlights in column G don't show correctly for the clients past client 1 in column C. Example of my workbook attached.

I'm using this VBA - but only receiving the correct highlights for the first client (Client A_BB). However the results for Clients A_BG and A_JJ are not showing the correct highlights for column G.

```
Sub compare_cols()

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim lastCell As Long

    'Get the last row
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Cells
        For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Cells
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                Exit For
                End If
        Next
    Next

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Cells
        For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Cells
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `Exit For` statements?

Comment: Pls show the exact content of the relevant datas in the two columns. A snapshot is good.

Comment: If you want to do it per client, you need to share the location of the client column for each column range.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line in your code (there is a title row)

```
   lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
```

This is the result i got

[image]

After your comment info pls. check this version

```
Sub compare_cols()

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim lastCell As Long

    'Get the last row
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Interior.Color = xlNone
    'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow
    'ReDim backrng(lastRow - 2)
    backrng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
    Range("A2:A" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates 1
    custnames = Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Value
    Range("A2:A" & lastRow) = backrng

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each custname In custnames
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Cells
        If custname = c.Offset(0, -2) Then
            For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Cells
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
                If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
                    c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Next

    For Each custname In custnames
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Cells
        If c.Interior.Color <> vbRed Then
        For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Cells
            If custname = d.Offset(0, -2) Then
                 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) <> 0) Then
                     c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                     Exit For
                 Else
                     c.Interior.Color = vbRed
                 End If
            End If
        Next
        End If
    Next
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - that helps, but it still doesn't help with the reflecting what is missing from column C in column G. The more I look at this, I'm not sure if it can be accomplished. Example - Customer A_BB is missing packages A_cd and F_hi. This code is capturing that all customers are missing A_zz and F_hi which is great. However, customer A_BB is missing A_cd. Customer A_JJ is missing B_ex, C_im. Thanks for your input